# Cocos2d-x 3 beta : polygon not drawn right

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Im using DrawNode as recommended to draw polygon but the problem its not drawn right as i like i attaching the image of the desired polygon shape and one that is output of my code that output wrong .
the code :

```
if (sprite && sprite->init())
{
        sprite->setTextureRect( Rect(0, 0, 200 ,200) );
        sprite->autorelease();        
        auto draw = DrawNode::create();

        {

        Point Block1[] = {
            Point(0,0),
            Point(30,0),
            Point(50,10),        
            Point(80,10),
            Point(100,0),    
            Point(200,0),
            Point(200,40),               
            Point(100,40), 
            Point(80,50),
            Point(50,50),
            Point(30,40),
            Point(0,40)
        };



        draw->drawPolygon(Block1,12 ,Color4F(1,222,120,1), 1, Color4F(0,0,1,1));
        } 
        sprite->addChild(draw, 10); 

 }
 else
 {
        CC_SAFE_DELETE(sprite);
 }
```

This is the output of the code it is wrong 
[image: The Wrong output]

this is the polygon i like to be drawn ( never mind the colors) 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I know that as of the first release of Cocos2d-iphone v3 it still does not support concave polygons. So, you probably need to triangulate the polygon and then drawPolygon. I have done this with both the library poly2tri (https://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/) and a simple Triangulation C++ class (http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Efficient_Polygon_Triangulation.shtml). Both of these work great if you have no transparency, but a little bit of aliasing causes strange effect if you are using transparency because the triangles have a miniscule amount of overlap.

I know that cocos2d-iphone will have support for concave polygons in the near future (I can see it in one of the branches where they are doing a re-write of the renderer).

Answer (score 2):

The way the polygons are drawn in cocos2d 3.4 depends on the order of points in you array. Without modification it could probably work if you put the first point of your `Block1[]` array inside/in the center of the bridge. This is because the cocos2d uses by default `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` flag to draw complex objects.

If you want a better solution. Go to `CCDrawNode.cpp` file in cocos2d source code and replace the flag `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` by `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`.

[image]

Afterwards check google for the order of points to draw the polygons with this flag. It is exactly very well suited to draw the objects like yours.

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation. But I can't find `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` in `CCDrawNode.cpp` class.